# Cannot get startX / Xorg to work on freeBSD 8.1

Tags: xorg, freebsd, system-installation, xrandr

I am following [this](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/x-config.html) link for Xorg configuration on FreeBSD 8.1

After this step:

```
Xorg -config xorg.conf.new -retro
```

I can see the screen and mouse is also working but I cannot exit out of it any way.

I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>, but it's not working.

**Edit:0** Xorg.0.log - http://pastebin.com/bCh53nPR

**Edit:2** `xorg.conf.new` http://pastebin.com/WPDnBBQy

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? You can't get to any of the TTYs (F1-F7)? Is your keyboard working at all?

Comment: Nope, I dont. After issuing the command I mentioned, I cannot switch to anywhere. blank screen all the way till I reboot.

Comment: So, in X your input devices work, but you have no TTYs? That seems a completely different problem.

Comment: Did you have a look at `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`? It may contain information about the problems with your keyboard.

Comment: @jasonwryan You miss the point - hari cannot *switch* to the ttys - but they are certainly working, since the Xorg was started from a tty!

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz So it would seem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it was revealed on chat, the actual problem lied in `/etc/hosts` not set up to recognize the local hostname. On some systems, including FreeBSD, the Xorg will halt trying to query the hostname of your machine before it becomes usable. So before starting X, one should ensure that the `/etc/hosts` file contains at least the line

```
127.0.0.1 localhost your_hostname_here localhost.my.domain
```

That is, the line has to contain the hostname.

---

Also, when you have such problems it might be a good idea to start an ssh daemon before running Xorg - then if you cannot do anything under X, you'll be able to log to your computer from another machine (if you have one at hand) and kill the Xorg. It will prevent the risk of data corruption on hard-reset and also spare you some time.

Comment: let me try what you are saying and thanks for the suggestion to have ssh access from other box.

Comment: I am getting checkered screen with mouse on that. An I cannot switch between ttys.

Comment: Ah, then you probably don't have xterm installed! What does `which xterm` output?

Comment: I have, I believe: it shows: /usr/local/bin/xterm

Comment: Hm, strange... Maybe you have some weird shell by default. So try `startx /usr/local/bin/xterm -- -config xorg.conf.new -retro` instead.

Comment: But did you look at the `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` as I suggested in my comment to your question? It should reveal any keyboard-driver related problems.

Comment: @hari let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1210/discussion-between-rozcietrzewiacz-and-hari)

Comment: I am waiting for you in chat room. Thanks much.

Comment: So keyboard is working fine before but it can go wrong after startx?